# Taking fixed direction on hemisphere and project to normal (openGL)

Tags: opengl, multisampling

I am trying to perform sampling using hemisphere around a surface normal. I want to experiment with fixed directions (and maybe jitter slightly between frames). So I have those directions:

```
vec3 sampleDirections[6] = {vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), 
                            vec3(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.866025f),
                            vec3(0.823639f, 0.5f, 0.267617f),
                            vec3(0.509037f, 0.5f, -0.700629f),
                            vec3(-0.509037f, 0.5f, -0.700629),
                            vec3(-0.823639f, 0.5f, 0.267617f)};
```

now I want the first direction to be projected on the normal and the others accordingly.

I tried these 2 codes, both failing.
This is what I used for random sampling (it doesn't seem to work well, the samples seem to be biased towards a certain direction) and I just used one of the fixed directions instead of s (here is the code of the random sample, when i used it with the fixed direction i didn't use theta and phi).

```
vec3 CosWeightedRandomHemisphereDirection( vec3 n, float rand1, float rand2 )
    float  theta = acos(sqrt(1.0f-rand1));
    float  phi = 6.283185f * rand2;

    vec3 s = vec3(sin(theta) * cos(phi), sin(theta) * sin(phi), cos(theta));

    vec3 v = normalize(cross(n,vec3(0.0072, 1.0, 0.0034)));
    vec3 u = cross(v, n);
    u = s.x*u;
    v = s.y*v;
    vec3 w = s.z*n;

    vec3 direction = u+v+w;
    return normalize(direction); 
}
```

** EDIT **

This is the new code

```
vec3 FixedHemisphereDirection( vec3 n, vec3 sampleDir)
{
    vec3 x;
    vec3 z;

    if(abs(n.x) < abs(n.y)){
        if(abs(n.x) < abs(n.z)){
            x = vec3(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
        }else{
            x = vec3(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
        }
    }else{
        if(abs(n.y) < abs(n.z)){
            x = vec3(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
        }else{
            x = vec3(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
        }
    }

    z = normalize(cross(x,n));
    x = cross(n,z);

    mat3 M = mat3(  x.x, n.x, z.x,
                    x.y, n.y, z.y,
                    x.z, n.z, z.z);
    return M*sampleDir;
}
```

So if my `n = (0,0,1);` and my `sampleDir = (0,1,0);` shouldn't the `M*sampleDir` be (0,0,1)? Cause that is what I was expecting.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with quaterions:

```
vec3 sv=normalize(sampleDirections[x]);
vec3 hv=normalize(sv+vec3(0, 1, 0));
vec4 q=vec4(cross(sv, hv), dot(sv, hv));
vec3 rot_n=2*(cross(q.xyz, cross(q.xyz, n) + q.w*n) + n;
```

Instead of storing sampleDirections, you should store the quaternion/matrix rotations of the vector to optimize computations in a shader.

Answer (score 0):

In order to transform the hemisphere points into the space of the normal, you need to set up a coordinate frame. Your second example is closer to something which will work, but keep in mind that you should only construct M once. Basically, your code fails because it makes a comparison between vectors. Such operations make very little geometric sense, because round off errors mean two vectors are rarely the same. (Your normal will almost never be exactly `vec3(1,0,0)`.)

To specify a coordinate frame in 3D, you only need two vectors orthogonal to each other. The third can be computed via the cross product. You already have one, which is the normal, and will become the eventual "Y" axis. To find the "X" axis, we need to pick a vector with a low absolute value of the dot product (i.e. close to orthogonal) with our "Y" axis, take their cross product and normalize, which gives us "Z", and then compute the true "X" from the cross product of "Y" and "Z".

We observe if the normal is `n` then the dot product between some `X` and `n` is `n.x * X.x + n.y * X.y + n.z * X.z`. Let us select `X` from `<1,0,0>`, `<0,1,0>` and `<0,0,1>`. Then to minimize the dot product, we just select the one of these three which corresponds with the minimum component of `n`. For example, if `|n.x| > |n.y| < |n.z|`, we would choose `<0,1,0>` because `n.y` has the smallest value. An alternative is to take the maximum component, zero out the others, and then shift it by 1 component cyclically (e.g. `<0.4,-.2,0.6> -> <0,0,0.6> -> <0.6,0,0>`.)

This technique means that you will have discontinuities in the orientation of the samples where the smallest component of the normal changes. (This pattern will look like a cube with X's across the faces.) Due to the [hairy ball theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem), discontinuities are unavoidable.

Comment: so if I have n as the Y axis and pick one of the three <1,0,0>, <0,1,0> and <0,0,1>, even if it is not actually orthogonal, will it work anyway? Let's say I have <0.4, -0.2, 0.6> I would select <0,1,0> but it is not orthogonal. Have I understood correctly?

Comment: Yes. The cross product is orthogonal to both vectors. The reason we select different ones depending on the maximum is to give us an *almost* orthogonal vector.

Comment: I edited with the new piece of code. It still works only if the normal is (0,1,0) or (0,-1,0).

Comment: still not working, any help?